saving the results of a function in a data frame that returns counts and ggplot
I wrote a function that returns me a list containing a number (odchylka.sr) and a ggplot object (ggpl)
model.ARIMA.RF.fct <- function (l.obs.pomin) { 

  ...
  wynik.lst <- list (odchylka.sr, ggpl)
  return(wynik.lst)

}


I save the results in a data frame according to
ARIMA.RF.cwu.wyniki <- data.frame(
  l.obs.pomin = c(52, 69, 136, 217)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    out = pmap(list (l.obs.pomin), model.ARIMA.RF.fct)
  )

I receive

I want the odchylka.sr to be a separate column before the 'out' column.
I can't cope with this task.
I use pmap because my target function has 3 arguments.
When I use the solution from unnest:
ARIMA.RF.cwu.wyniki <- data.frame(
  l.obs.pomin = c(52, 69, 136, 217)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    out = pmap(list (l.obs.pomin), model.ARIMA.RF.fct)
  )|> unnest(out) 

I get a result close to what I expected, but I can't convert it to wide format



library(tidyverse)
function_that_returns_lists <- function(x){
  thing_2 <- ggplot () +
    geom_point(aes (x = c(1,2,3), y = c(18,5,2)))
  
  tibble(thing_1 = x+1,
       thing_2 = list(thing_2)) # properly wrap the outputs for a tibble container ggplots must be in lists
}

df1 <- tibble(
  l.obs.pomin = c(52, 69, 136, 217)
) %>% 
  mutate(
    out = pmap_df(list (l.obs.pomin), function_that_returns_lists) # pmap_df so out is more conveniently structured
  ) |> unnest(out)


when thing_2 <- ggplot () + geom_point(aes (x = c(1,2,3), y = c(18,5,2))) I get an error message:
Error in mutate():
ℹ In argument: out = pmap_df(list(l.obs.pomin), function_that_returns_lists).
Caused by error in dplyr::bind_rows():
! Argument 1 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector.
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.

ggplots can live in a tibble if contained in a list. so keeping the pmap and unnest but rework the function that returns lists (now badly named as it returns tibbles)
